# Software to estimate the remaining tasks based on previous estimated and actual time realised for completion?

Tags: windows, web-apps, project-management

I need to evaluate the time of remaining tasks based on the actual time and estimated time of completed tasks. Preferably there would be Gant charts displayed, the original chart and a rescaled Gant chart based on history of actual time vs estimated times.

For example if a small project had 4 tasks and each task was estimated at 2 days. Lets say 2 tasks were completed at 4 days each, the reminding tasks should be projected to be completed in 4 days, therefore rescaling all the remaining tasks and getting a new project time line, with each reminding task being projected to 4 days as well.

Anyone know of such an auto estimation and projection software ?

Comment: Any decent project planning software should be able to give you that. Sometimes it uses the term *baseline* for a stored (previous) estimate. Your question is also not complete: what OS/online? What price? Input/output requirements? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] your question

Comment: You are looking for "Evidence Based Scheduling" - see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_Scheduling  if you find it anywhere other than in http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/, please let me know. Especially if it is free.